# Add custom background-color in Atomic CSS

Tags: css

I'm using [Atomic CSS](http://acss.io/), and I'd like to set for element a `background-color`, with a help of `Bgc(value)`.

I tried, set it with `Bgc(#FF0)` or `Bgc(rgb(255, 255, 0))`, but Atomic compiler, didn't write to my stylesheet file, from this rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [lowercase for color values](http://acss.io/frequently-asked-questions.html#why-do-i-have-to-use-lowercase-for-color-values-):

> To prevent redundancy, we made the choice to favor lowercase over uppercase, even though the latter is valid.
>
> This is because classes such as `C(#fff)` and `C(#FFF)` would not duplicate the declaration but would add an unnecessary selector to the style sheet.